# How to use htmlentities with special characters

Tags: php

I'm having a very difficult with non-utf8 characters showing up in text that is being saved in a database. Just some of the more common characters I've been finding are:

```
—
–
“
”
‘
’
```

I am using `htmlentities` to escape any utf-8 quotes that have been added to the text by our users.

```
htmlentities( $string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8" )
```

Because of the special characters above, I am now getting the following error message from htmlentities:

```
htmlentities(): Invalid multibyte sequence in argument
```

Is there a way to deal with these special characters? I'd like to convert them to utf8 but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: What are the smart quotes doing in there in the first place? *"Is there a way to deal with these special characters?"* --- A: You don't use them, period.

Comment: This is text that is being copied from other sites and pasted into the application, then saved in a database

Comment: Again, don't use them. Use standard character replacements. Why are you copying those in the first place from a website?

Comment: Our users are not using them. The smart quotes are being copied from other websites. The users have been told to replace them with utf8 characters but they are obviously missing some of them, as evidenced by the multibyte error message

Comment: Then you'll need or they'll need to use functions such as str_replace, preg_replace etc.

Comment: I've tried to use str_replace but str_replace misses some of the smart quotes. Maybe I'm not doing it correctly but would it look like this? `str_replace('”','',$string)`

Comment: You'll need to use 2 seperate functions. `str_replace('”','',$string)` and `str_replace('’','',$string)` or try and find a script that will do it all in one shot. There are some, I've seen them before. I don't have any use for them anymore. Find the functions on PHP.net to read up on them to get the proper syntax if required.

Comment: Am I supposed to be matching the actual character itself or should I be matching on a hex value?

Comment: The character itself.